# Why Next.js middleware rewrite is not running twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, middleware

### Next.js Middleware is not running

I'm trying to use next.js [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware), and I got in a situation that I need two redirects. One to change Desktop URL to Mobile URL, and another to change searchParams in URL.

The first one is a root/top middleware and the second one lower in route. **I don't know why, but the SearchParams Middleware IS NOT RUNNING when the desktop midlleware is executed before it. Is not suppose to run both?**

### Desktop rewrite:

```
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const { pathname } = req.nextUrl
    const userAgent = req.headers.get('user-agent')

    if (matchDesktop(pathname, userAgent)) {
        return NextResponse.rewrite(`/desktop${req.nextUrl.pathname}`)
    }
}
```

### SearchParams Filter rewrite:

```
export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname, origin } = req.nextUrl
  const page = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get('page') || DEFAULT_PAGE
  const sortBy = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get('sortBy') || DEFAULT_SORT_BY

  return NextResponse.rewrite(`${origin}${pathname}${page}/${sortBy}`)
}
```

#### Folder Structure

**Desktop middleware:** pages > _middleware.ts

**SearchParams midleware:** pages > store > category > _middleware.ts

Comment: What version of Next.js are you on? From Next.js 12.2, you can only use a single `middleware.js` file that needs to be at the same level as the `pages` folder. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-upgrade-guide#no-nested-middleware.

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks, I'm kinda figured out what happens, I will use this to complement my answer 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It's not possible to do two rewrites

What I'm doing here is not a redirect, it's a rewrite.

I don't know why, but I figured out that is not possible to do two redirects, I think they don't follow the entire flow of normal access so the second one it's never reached.

The way to do this is to use a `NextResponse.redirect` **not** a `NextResponse.rewrite`.

**Be sure to do that, because can ruin your SEO.**

**Next.js 12.2 or up**

From Next.js 12.2, you can only use a single middleware.js file that needs to be at the same level as the pages folder.